# on the least primitive root of a prime

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

There is an article in this [link](http://msp.org/pjm/1957/7-1/pjm-v7-n1-p05-s.pdf). I am trying to understand it but some parts seem unclear to me.
For example in part 3 I don't know how the following was derived:
$$
\left ( 2^{m}-1 \right )p^{\frac{1}{2}}\left [ \frac{x}{2} \right ]\geq \left [ \frac{x}{2} \right ]^{2}
$$
Can anyone kindly explain it?

$m$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $p−1$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor ^2 \leq \sum_{\substack{d | p-1 \\ d>1}} \frac{|\mu(d)|}{\phi(d)} \sum_{o(\chi)=d} p^{1/2} \left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor.$$

The inner sum is over Dirichlet characters of order $d$ and modulus $p$.  There are $\phi(d)$ of those, so we have

$$\left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor ^2 \leq \sum_{\substack{d | p-1 \\ d>1}} |\mu(d)| p^{1/2} \left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor.$$

Note that the Mobius function $\mu(d)$ is supported on square-free numbers.  There are precisely $2^m$ square-free divisors $d$ of $p-1$, but we exclude $d=1$, so we have

$$\left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor ^2 \leq (2^m-1) p^{1/2} \left\lfloor \frac x 2 \right \rfloor.$$

Comment: you mean $\sum_{o(\chi )=d}^{ }1=\varphi (d)\$?

Comment: Yes.  The group of Dirichlet characters of prime $p$ modulus is cyclic.  In any cyclic group, the number of elements of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function (assuming $d$ divides the size of the group).

Comment: I have some questions in this article,can we talk more on emails?

Comment: can you answer me?

Comment: I suggest you post any additional questions here.  Then I or others can answer them.